# Wkhtmltopdf. Word-break break-all

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I have problems with converting to PDF. I get the impression that word-break break-all does not work, I seem to have climbed a branch, but nothing helped me. Everything is fine in the browser, but the PDF output looks like this. Thanks for the help.

HERE IS A screenshot:

[image: HERE IS A screenshot]

```html
<div class="ticket-info-defense-name">
2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51 2024-03-09 QWERTYUIO 5B5B4688 BC5B9C51
</div>
```

```css
.ticket-info-defense-name {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100pt;
   max-width: 100pt;
   font-size: 7pt;
   color: #a2a2a1;
   height: 41pt;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: justify;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   -ms-word-break: break-all;
   word-break: break-all;
   -ms-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
   -webkit-hyphens: auto;
   hyphens: auto;
 }
```

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is probably simply too old, to support such newer CSS features. If you check the repo, you'll see that the last changes where made 2+ years ago, and the author has _archived_ the whole thing over a year ago. https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: I was about to post a similar comment to CBroe. For more details on the status, see [this article by its last maintainer](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html) (which is itself out of date, since even the 0.12.7 release never seems to have happened). On the other hand, [MDN's word-break compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#browser_compatibility) shows support in Safari 3 (2007) and Chrome 1 (2008), so it _should_ work even in a library based on 2012-vintage WebKit.